# I can't add ImagePipeline to my scrapy script

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm developing a script to download images from any web, but I'm in some troubles with it. I know that it's developed as shit but...I need it for a course using scrapy, so here it goes:

When I throw the script, this shows in the terminal a list of URLs parsed in "image_urls."

```
{'image_urls': [u'https://thehackerway.files.wordpress.com/2017/04/1.png?w=595&h=382',
            u'https://thehackerway.files.wordpress.com/2017/04/2.png?w=595&h=327',...}
```

But the image doesn't download. I checked all the prompt/output, and I discovered that, in theory, the ItemPipeline wasn't charge

```
[scrapy] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:[]
```

I'm going to let you the code right here, I tried so hard with different setups, but it wasn't successful. I need your help in this.

```
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy import Request
from scrapy.item import Item, Field
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.xlib.pydispatch import dispatcher
from twisted.internet import reactor
from scrapy import signals
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.settings import Settings
from scrapy.pipelines.images import ImagesPipeline


class HackerWayItem(Item):
    image_urls = Field()
    images = Field()

class BloggerSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name="TheHackerWay"
    start_urls=['https://thehackerway.com']
    allowed_domains=['thehackerway.com']
    #custom_setting ={
    #   'ITEM_PIPELINES' : 'scrapy.pipelines.images.ImagesPipeline',
    #   'IMAGES_STORE': '/home/bodhidharma/Escritorio/Practicas/Images/',
    #   'MEDIA_ALLOW_REDIRECTS': 'True'
    #}
    #settings = Settings()
    #settings = get_project_settings()
    #settings.set('ITEM_PIPELINES':     {'scrapy.pipelines.images.ImagesPipeline':1})
    rules = [Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=['.'], allow_domains=['thehackerway.com']), callback='parse_blog')]

def parse_blog(self, response):
    print "link parseado %s" % response.url
    hxs = Selector(response)
    item = HackerWayItem()
    #urls = hxs.xpath("//img/@src").extract()
    #for u in urls:
    #item ['image_urls']=u
    item ['image_urls'] = hxs.xpath("//img/@src").extract()
    #item ['image_urls']=hxs.xpath("//*[@id='post-3762']/div[2]/p[24]/a/img/@src").extract()
    #item ['file_urls']=hxs.xpath("@href").extract()
    yield item
    #print (self.settings.attributes.values())
    #print (item)
    #return item # Retornando el Item.


def catch_item(sender, item, **kwargs):
    #print ("Item Extraido: ")#, item
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    dispatcher.connect(catch_item, signal=signals.item_passed)
    dispatcher.connect(reactor.stop, signal=signals.spider_closed)


    spider = BloggerSpider()

    process = CrawlerProcess({
'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)'
    })

    process.crawl(spider)
    print ("\n[+] Starting scrapy engine...")
    #crawler.start()
    #reactor.run()

    process.start()
```

Comment: Your source file indentation is incorrect. Also, you have `custom_settings` which enable the `ImagesPipeline` commented, isn't this the reason?

Comment: Hi! I tried with custom_settings configuration but it wasn't work (you can try it, this is the full script). About de indentation problem...in what line?.